# grep multiple numeric search

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to do a grep search to match times. For example I would like to match the following phrases:

```
12 45 am in CA
It is currently 3 45 am
16 45 pm is the current time
3 23pm in a few hours
10 00 is the best time
```

I tried using:

```
grep '[0-12] [0-5][[0-9]]( ){0,1}(am|pm){0,1}'
```

Right now my output doesn't make sense. Am I supposed to be escaping some of the characters if so which ones and why?

Comment: Is `10 00` also a match as per time?

Comment: @user3218114 can you give an example of the desired output please? It's not clear, to me, if you are trying to get the full phrase or just the digits.

Comment: does `10 is the best time` match?

Answer (score 1):

`[0-12]` is a [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that tells the regex engine to match only one out of several characters.

Here `0-1` will represents the range from 0 to 1. So finally it will match only 0,1 and 2.

---

#### Time in 12-Hour Format Regular Expression Pattern:

```
(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]) [0-5]?[0-9] ?([ap]m)?
```

Description:

```
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    0?                       '0' (optional)
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
   |                        OR
    1                        '1'
    [0-2]                    any character of: '0' to '2'
  )                        end of \1
                           ' '
  [0-5]                    any character of: '0' to '5' (optional)
  [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
                           ' ' (optional)
  (                        group and capture to \2 (optional):
    [ap]                     any character of: 'a', 'p'
    m                        'm'
  )?                       end of \2
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mJ7lN6/3) as well.

---

#### Few points about your regex pattern:

`( ){0,1}` can be converted to `[ ]?` or simply `single space followed by ?` where `?` matches it zero and one time

`(am|pm)` can be converted to `[ap]m`

`[[0-9]]` there is no need to use double brackets

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason that this command works for egrep and not grep? Is there a way to make this work with grep without any extra options?

Comment: sorry I just know a little bit about regex pattern. No idea about `grep` command.

Comment: nvm figured it out! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**12 hour formate:**

```
\b([0]{0,1}[0-9]|1[01]) [0-5][0-9]{0,1}\s{0,1}(am|pm){0,1}
```

**OUTPUT:**

- 3 45 am
- 3 23pm
- 10 00

**24 hour formate:**

```
 \b([01]{0,1}[0-9]|2[0-3]) [0-5][0-9]{0,1}\s{0,1}(am|pm){0,1}
```

**OUTPUT:**

- 12 45 am
- 3 45 am
- 16 45 pm
- 3 23pm
- 10 00

Comment: Somehow this didn't work for me. what does  ([01]{0,1}[0-9]|2[0-3]) match. especially the part of 2[0-3]. What exactly is this matching?

Comment: @user3218114 yes! it is 24 hours format. can you show "Somehow this didn't work for me."?  user0750474

Comment: @Tim.Tang OP needs 12 hours format as per the sample and regex pattern.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason that this command works for egrep and not grep? Is there a way to make this work with grep without any extra options?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

`grep '[0-9]\{1\} [0-9]\{2\}' time.test`

For example, with the following test file:

```
$ cat time.test
12 45 am in CA
It is currently 3 45 am
16 45 pm is the current time
3 23pm in a few hours
10 00 is the best time
3 is just a number
also my favorite number is 13
how about the current year 2014
```

The output is:

```
$ grep '[0-9]\{1\} [0-9]\{2\}' time.test
12 45 am in CA
It is currently 3 45 am
16 45 pm is the current time
3 23pm in a few hours
10 00 is the best time
```

Since am and pm are inconsistent (may or may not show up), it's possible to reduce the problem to only `grep`ing two numbers with a space in between.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ugh. There is no need to specify `\{1\}` repetition of anything, ever.